# How to call an internal endpoint in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to figure out how I can call an internal endpoint and get the response in Ktor. I saw posts on how to redirect internally but they do not return the response.

For example. I have a get request that returns foo. I have another get request that returns bar. I have a getrequest that should return foobar. Instead of rewriting the logic in foo and bar, I could just call those endpoints themselves.

```
get("/foo") {
    call.respondText("foo") // except without relying on client to handle HTTP
}
get("/bar") {
    call.respondText("bar")
}
get("/foobar") {
    call.respondText(get("/foo") + get("/bar")) // returns foobar
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do here is abstract the functionality into functions, and then call these functions. However, I'd keep the processing of the request and response individual to each route.

```kotlin
get("/foo") {
    val result = functionHandlingFoo()
    // send out result here
}
get("/bar") {
    val result = functionHandlingBar()
    // send out result here
}
get("/foobar") {
    val resultFoo = functionHandlingFoo()
    val resultBar = functionHandlingBar()
    // process result and send out
}
```